# How can I stop losing my info each time I switch of Ubuntu from my usb stick

Tags: boot, software-installation

Each time I power on or restart my laptop Ubuntu always refreshes back to being new an I had already installed some apps and done some work. I am using Ubuntu from a flash disk and I would really love not to be going through the same thing over and over

Comment: You need to perform an installation for the system to be permanent. If you each time boot the live USB, it will be the same initial session always.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep using your USB flash drive and not install ubuntu permanently, and also wish to make changes permanent - you'll need to create something called persistent storage.
This will make your live boot load a swap partition every time you boot it.

Here is a documented ubuntu guide of how to do so from ubuntu OS: 
[LiveUsbPendrivePersistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)

Here is a method of doing so using Rufus from Windows OS: [Rufus: Creating A Persistent Storage Live USB With Ubuntu Or Debian From Windows](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/rufus-creating-persistent-storage-live.html#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20persistent%20storage,setting%20the%20persistent%20partition%20size.)

And here is a quick video with brief explanation: [How to create a live USB drive with persistent storage in Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScCUDX5gtRw)
The video demonstrates the basic usage of mkusb app. You might not need to add a ppa repository.

Or as suggested - install the OS for good.